# How to combine two JSON objects into an array

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

I have two JSON files - one pertaining to English Premier League data of 2015-16 and other of 2016-17. The JSON data in each file is as follows (extract only):

```
{
  "name": "English Premier League 2015/16",
  "rounds": [
    {
      "name": "Matchday 1",
      "matches": [
       {
          "date": "2015-08-08",
           "team1": {
            "key": "manutd",
            "name": "Manchester United",
            "code": "MUN"
          },
          "team2": {
            "key": "tottenham",
            "name": "Tottenham Hotspur",
            "code": "TOT"
          },
          "score1": 1,
          "score2": 0
        },
```

and so on... lot of name, matches like this in the rounds array.

The data of 2016-17 is similar to above:

```
{
  "name": "English Premier League 2016/17",
  "rounds": [
    {
      "name": "Matchday 1",
      "matches": [
        {
          "date": "2016-08-13",
          "team1": {
            "key": "hull",
            "name": "Hull City",
            "code": "HUL"
          },
          "team2": {
            "key": "leicester",
            "name": "Leicester City",
            "code": "LEI"
          },
          "score1": 2,
          "score2": 1
        },
```

and so on... lot of name, matches like this in the rounds array.

These two are in two separate json files. I am developing an application in Angular 2 and have used a data service to get this data. That part was successful. However I need to use ngFor for creating rows in table and for that I require this data to be iterable like an array.

I have tried to convert these two json objects into an array but could not succeed.

1 I have initialised an empty array and tried to do array.push for each object. That did not work

```
arr=[];
if(this.data1516!=null && this.data1516!=undefined) {arr.push(this.data1516);}
if(this.data1617!=null && this.data1617!=undefined) {arr.push(this.data1617);}
```

2 I tried Object. assign -

`this.obj=Object.assign({},this.data1516,this.data1617);`

and then tried converting the object into array, even that did not work

All I want the final json single file to be an array of those two objects, like this:

[ {obj1} , {obj2} ]

Answer (score 1):

There was a extra `]` inside `arr.push`

This should work :

```
arr=[];

if(this.data1516!=null && this.data1516!=undefined) {
    arr.push(this.data1516);
}

if(this.data1617!=null && this.data1617!=undefined) {
    arr.push(this.data1617);
}
```

OR Shorter version (ES6)

```
arr = [ ...this.data1516 , ...this.data1617 ];
```

Comment: that extra ] was not in the code, by mistake - corrected it